# transformation of trigonometric graphs

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Thomas calculus for the following function:

$$
  f(x) = A\ Sin(\frac{2π}B (x-C))+D
$$
says that |A| is the amplitude , |B| is the period, C is the horizontal shift, and D is the vertical shift.

which general formula,
horizontal shifts have the form:  **y=f(x+h)**
vertical shifts have the form:    **y=f(x)+h**
period is supposed to be the positive number **p** such that **f(x+p)=f(x)**

I can see how A is the amplitude and D is the vertical shift, but **I don't really get how |B| is the period and C is the horizontal shift**

I could simplify the function to this:

$$
  f(x) = A\ Sin(\frac{1}B (x-C))+D
$$
what else can we do here? How do we simplify this to the above mentioned general form or something to make the value of the horizontal shift and period more popping out clearly in the equation? How does the period become **B** and the horizontal shift **C**?

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate how $|B|$ is the period, simply evaluate $f(x+\lvert B \rvert)$,
\begin{align}
f(x+\lvert B \rvert) &= A \sin\Big(\frac{2\pi}{B}(x+|B|-C)\Big) +D \\
&=A\sin\Big(\frac{2\pi}{B}(x-C) \pm 2\pi \Big) + D \\
&=f(x)
\end{align}
so that $|B|$ is *a* period.  The $\pm$ enters the equation because $B$ and $|B|$ may have different signs and the period by convention is usually taken to be positive.  Strictly you need to show $|B|$ is the least such number, which you can try do do, possibly using the addition formula for the sine function.

That $C$ is the $x$-shift should be obvious by your own definition since it applies a fixed subtraction directly and only to the $x$ variable.

Comment: how would t the horizontal shift be: C ? Since, 1/B is multiplying x and C, it's not sin(x-C) it's sin(x/B - c/B), so that doesn't quite make sense, could you please explain a bit?

Comment: The multiplier $1/B$ affects *both* $C$ and $x$ equally, so that the shift along the $x$-axis is governed only by $C$.  Maybe it would be easiest to see if you try it out with a few numbers and a calculator:  Take $C=0$ as the base case;  then try with $C=1$.  The graph shifts just one unit along.

Comment: it is governed by C, that I see, but, it actually shifts with a factor of C/B ? and the multiplier also stretches the graph before it actually shifts because it multiplies x before it does the shift?

Comment: Yes, I think you have got it.  Another way, amounting to the same, is that it shifts $x/B$ by $C/B$.